# javascript touchend not firing

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why, but I can not get my touchend event to fire.  I have tried on both an android phone, as well as desktop chrome; and I keep getting the same results.

```
let activeZoom = document.getElementsByClassName('active-magic-slide')[0];
  let header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
  var headerVisible = true;
  
  let zoomActivated = () => {
    console.log('show zoom')
    headerVisible = !headerVisible;
    if (!headerVisible){
      header.style.visibility="hidden";
    } else {
      header.style.visibility="revert";
    }
  }
  let touchZoom = () =>{
    console.log('touch')

    headerVisible = !headerVisible;
    if (!headerVisible){
      header.style.background="green";
    } else {
      header.style.background="white";
    }
  }

  // console.log(activeZoom);
  activeZoom.addEventListener('mouseover',zoomActivated);
  activeZoom.addEventListener('mouseleave',zoomActivated);
  activeZoom.addEventListener('touchstart',touchZoom);
  // activeZoom.ontouchEnd = zoomActivated();
  activeZoom.addEventListener('touchend',touchZoom);
```

The first bit about the mouseover/mouseleave works just fine.  So I would have expected my touchstart/touchend to work the same way.  However, it does not.  When I touch the element, it will turn the header green (as expected).  But, when I remove my finger then header stays green until I touch it again (not expected).  I have console logged it out, and I can not see at any time that the touchend is actually getting triggered.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

let touchZoom = () =>{
console.log('touch')

```
headerVisible = !headerVisible;
if (headerVisible){
  header.style.background="green";
} else {
  header.style.background="white";
}
```

}

Try rewriting your touchZoom like this.

Comment: Since you already toggled the value initially